# How do I navigate within a select2 Element

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

When I create an select2 Element, the library creates some "span" tags beside my original select tag (which is not displayed anymore). How do I navigate to the span that "imitates" my select Element, in order to, for example, change its background color?

```
$("#mySelect").select2();
var mySelect2Span = $("#mySelect").doSomethingThatReturnsTheCorrespondingSpan();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#mySelect").data("select2").$selection;
```

gives you what you want